# Як правильно: "трамвая" чи "трамваю"?

Tags: відмінювання, граматика, spelling, родовий-відмінок

Якщо дослідити ряд джерел, то виявиться, що існують обидва варіанти написання.

**Трамваю**

У пісні ["Бувай ми здорова"](http://nashe.com.ua/song/2443) (Львівське ретро):

> Куплю си ґазету, сяду до **трамваю**
>   Бувай ми здорова, я вже від’їжджаю (2)
>   Ґазету читаю, їду у **трамваю**
>   Бувай ми здорова, вже тя не чекаю

У вікіпедії:

> [Міжміський і приміський трамвай (інтерурбан)](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%86%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD) - вид рейкового
>   транспорту, що з'єднує різні міста або одне місто з його передмістями.
>   Інтерурбани відрізняються від звичайних залізниць тим, що організація
>   їх роботи набагато ближче до **трамваю**, що виражається зокрема в
>   більш легкому рухомому складі (як правило, електричному), частих
>   зупинках, легкій будові колії, пристрою суміщеної колії тощо. Нерідко
>   частина маршруту, що проходить по центру міста, нічим не відрізняється
>   від лінії звичайного міського **трамваю**.

**Трамвая**

Проте у Яна Рузького в творі "95-16" читаємо:

> Шель здригнувся. Відганяючи прикрі спогади, глянув на темну воду
>   міської канави. На спокійній поверхні ви­мальовувалися контури
>   похилених дерев. Він минув ясно освітлені вітрини Товарного Дому і
>   швидко пробіг Свидницьку вулицю. Перед клубом журналістів саме
>   зупини­лася "шістка". Шель зайшов до **трамвая** і спробував зга­дати
>   провідну думку перерваних роздумів.

Які правильно говорити і якими правилом потрібно керуватись?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Прийменник [*до*](http://sum.in.ua/s/do) в контексті напрямку руху керує **родовим відмінком** підпорядкованих слів.

Зауважимо, що *трамвай* — це іменник **чоловічого роду II відміни**.

А от стосовно самого родового відмінку таких іменників, правила української граматики, дійсно, складні.

Стаття на Вікіпедії [Родовий відмінок однини іменників чоловічого роду другої відміни](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2_%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83_%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B8) містить пояснення на цю тему (із посиланнями на кілька поважних джерел), що іменник дістає закінчення `-а/-я` або `-у/-ю` **в залежності від свого лексичного значення**:

> Іменники чоловічого роду другої відміни у родовому відмінку однини приймають закінчення `-а(я)` (залежно від групи іменника), коли вони мають значення:
>
> 8. Назви машин та їх деталей: *автомобіля, дизеля, комбайна, мотора, поршня, трактора, трамвая*

Відповідно, «до кого? до чого?» — *до трамва**я***.

Як завжди, можна спробувати відходити від граматичних правил для передачі емоцій або власного ставлення до обговорюваного питання, або просто для підкреслення діалектизму. Щоправда, ненаголошене закінчення слова може зменшити силу емоційного ефекту.

---

Словосполучення *їду у трамваї* простіше у цьому сенсі.

Прийменник [*у/в*](http://sum.in.ua/s/v) в контексті місцезнаходження керує **місцевим відмінком**, а слово [*трамвай*](https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B9#.D0.A3.D0.BA.D1.80.D0.B0.D1.97.D0.BD.D1.81.D1.8C.D0.BA.D0.B0) у місцевому відмінку має обидві форми: *у трамва**ї*** та *у трамва**ю***.

---

Посилання

- [Wikidot: Дзвона чи дзвону? або -А (-Я) чи -У (-Ю) в родовому відмінку](http://rodovyi-vidminok.wikidot.com/t)

Comment: http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/ також каже, що *трамва́я* у родовому (і прямого посилання теж не можна дати, ех :(

Comment: Можливо зробити так: http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B9

Comment: @ЄвгенФрік, наведена таблиця просто перелічує варіанти через кому і нічого не пояснює. Хіба не так?

Comment: Так. Я мав на увазі родовий відмінок та неможливість надати пряме посилання у коментарі @NashBridges.

Answer (score 6):

Цілком погоджуюся з відповіддю @bytebuster, та хочу додати своє щодо саме цього слова. Неодноразово натрапляв на таке правило (рекомендацію?):

- використовуємо закінчення `-я`, якщо йдеться про певну транспортну одиницю (*"зайшов до трамвая"*),
- а закінчення `-ю`, коли *трамвай* має загальне значення (*"лінія швидкісного трамваю"*).

Таке ж пишуть [це](http://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blog-olexandr-ponomariv-38957573) і [це](http://gazeta.ua/articles/chistota-movlennya/_slovnik-gortaj-a-svij-rozum-maj-movoznavec/468362) джерело.

Буду радий, якщо спільнота доповнить відповідь офіційними правилами.

Comment: я доречі це правило у школі запам'ятовував так: якщо маю сумніви, то `-а/-я` вживаю для більш конкретних, а `-у/-ю` для більш абстрактних іменників. тобто навпаки

Comment: @Chizh нас вчитель з музики в цьому "просвітив" :D А щодо слова "трамвай", то це начебто вийняток (контекст впливає на закінчення).